# PHP - SELECT query using PDO without injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have some variables that I want to check if any of them are exist in the database or not. Also I want to prevent injection. This is my code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password');
    if($result->rowCount($result)=='1') {
        echo 'Ok';
    } else echo 'Not Ok';
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks.

By the way, I have the class `$db` and It is working well.

Comment: Where you use `bindParam()` in your code??

Comment: This code can impossibly throw that error. Please show us the relevant code (like the actual line 7 of the `D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php` file.